# How to create a one line sign up form with this mailchimp code

Tags: forms, mailchimp

I'm looking to create a "one line sign up newsletter form" with mailchimp but their editor don't show how to it. I've been searching for hours but nothing works for me.

Here is the result & code I start with (don't know how to put code in there sorry) :

http://help.mailchimp.com/img/embedtrans2.jpg (result)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/20FBj.jpg (the code)

I would simply like to have the text field and subscribe button on the same line (the button and text field length will be reduced)

How to do it ? Thanks in advance !

PS : this is my first question here and I want to thanks to whole stack over flow community and the people that will eventually help me.

Comment: Look like I found a good css code to obtain a one lign sign up form with mailchimp : http://jsfiddle.net/DW2Xd/4/

Only problem, does anyone know how to shorten the text field and button so it fit well in any widget sidebar (wordpress).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

if you are using mailchimp then to make a single line is a simple CSS.

```
#mc_embed_signup input.email{
    display:inline-block;
}

#mc_embed_signup input.button {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

http://csnipp.com/s/504/-Make-mailchimp-signup-form-aligned-in-a-single-line